# Database design: using names to logically link records instead of "hard" IDs

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

**The situation**
I am developing a content management system in which there are modules and objects. Objects are linked to modules by using a `module_id` column. Many other tables/objects refer to these module/object combinations. I usually use the module/object `id` column to link other records to these.

However, back when I just started this system I would also sometimes use the module/object `name` columns. The logic behind this is that if a database is reinstalled, putting the data back is largely simplified, because the combination of module and object `name` is guaranteed to be unique (by virtue of a unique-key on those 2 fields). I can make no such assumptions about the `id` field, since if a module is added/removed when reinstalling the IDs can change (because more or fewer objects are added).

Currently my database uses almost exclusively IDs, except for some objects which really, really can't get their module/object combination wrong (such as the table handling the user permissions).
However, in the PHP code I use almost exclusively names, since it gives huge benefits in readability. See the following example:

```
Function definition: GetObjectRecord($module, $object, $record)

ObjectManagement::GetObjectRecord("pagemanagement", "page", 17);
ObjectManagement::GetObjectRecord(4, 26, 17);
```

Obviously, the first example (which is how I currently do it) is readable, and even someone who knows nothing about my system can see that I'm fetching `Page` 17 from the `PageManagement` module. The second example would mean nothing without first checking the database to find which object `module 4 object 26` refers to.
An additional benefit is that since my table naming convention is `moduleName_objectName`, I can often skip finding out the module/object IDs (for example: my query function creates the table name and checks user permissions using the names).

Because of this I'm considering replacing all references to object/module IDs in the database with their names.
So far I see the following advantages:

- it would be much harder to accidentally mess up a database since the IDs of modules/objects would no longer matter
- I would only rarely need to turn the module/object names (which I almost always have already) into the associated IDs, saving quite a few PHP function calls and `SELECT id FROM core_objects WHERE (name = ...);` queries
- the data in the database is more human-readable (very minor advantage)

I see the following disadvantages:

- obviously, doing more string-based comparison in most query `WHERE` clauses will be (slightly) slower (i.e. `WHERE id = #` is faster than `WHERE name = ...`)
- renaming a module and/or object would bring with it the same problems we'd otherwise have with changing IDs (but this has never happened yet, and would still be easier to fix than the same problem with IDs)

**The actual question**
I'm wondering what would be best practice. Would it be wise in this situation to use the names over the IDs?

Comment: The best practice is always establishing relations by primary key. Primary key is in many cases an integer, for multiple reasons, most notably the ease of creating one and naturally - performance. You can always give a string-based unique key to your records so you can refer to a record either by PK or by other index which is human-readable. If I were you, I would never establish relations using string-keys.

Comment: @Mjh I don't know if this was clear from my question, but this situation refers **only** to modules and objects. **All** other records in the database (so also the actual data records created for all objects) use the PK `id` column. An example where this would be an issue: objects can register themselves as *extensions* for a `Page` object. Currently the extension is linked to the object-id, but if the object ID changes on a reinstall, I have to walk past all these kinds of tables to update the ID to the new one. If I were to use the object name (which never changes) this would never go wrong.

Comment: You answered everything yourself. You know how relations are established. Your issue lies in this so-called "database reinstall". Since databases aren't some gigantic text files, the "reinstall" is usually done via a process called migration and then seeding. If you seed the data correctly (and establish relations using primary key `id`) then apparently your issue is gone forever. The other part of your question is the ease of referring to a record - if you add a string unique key to your record, you've solved that problem as well. Now all your problems are gone, albeit it's lengthy to code.

Comment: If you try establishing a relationship based on a text string, then you have to appreciate that it effectively becomes immutable, or that you have to update every related record when it is changed

Comment: @Mjh I'm not sure I follow you 100%. It is true that once I've re-seeded the database I can replace now-erroneous values in the original backup with the correct replacements, then insert the migrated data into the database. In fact, that is what I've been doing so far. My database contains both tables which will be filled with data generated by users, and tables which contain core-data which is more-or-less static. However, that static data is generated when installing/seeding, based on the settings specified in various .ini files, which module folders are present, etc. [...read next comment]

Comment: I'd argue that in some cases using strings of PKIs is absolutely fine ... as long as you can `ON UPDATE CASCADE` anywhere they're referenced. For instance, using ISO 4217 currency codes on a currency table and having the ID as a `CHAR(3)` field (*USD*, *GBP* etc).

Comment: So different customers may have completely different PKs for their modules and objects. Which makes automatic migration a bit of a **** since it would require me to fetch all relevant values from the old database, then reinstall, then run the old-->new replacement logic. It may very well be that this is best practice, in which case I'll comply, but I am trying to find out if the name-based solution I describe would be considered acceptable. It would remove the problem at its root. (I'm not just trying to find an answer, I'm also trying to get why it would be unacceptable.)

Comment: @MarkBaker: I know that means the strings should be immutable, but they already are right now (they are used for user permission checks, and used heavily within the PHP code). And the update-when-changed problem is the exact same problem I currently have with the `id` PKs, which may change on reinstall, so I'm trying to mitigate that by using values which are guaranteed not to change (without causing far-reaching consequences to begin with).

Comment: IDs shouldn't change on re-install; though they can be a PITA if you're trying to merge databases, which is why I use GUIDs these days

Comment: I use compound primary keys (where it makes sense, not everywhere), so you can always have PK such as `(id, customer_id)` - quite neat, doesn't really impact the performance, no need for `UUID` which Mark mentioned, database can still scale, you can still merge data etc. There's no reason why a name-based key would be unacceptable, it has its uses but after a few of these comments we've discovered further problems that you're facing. If in your case the name-based approach works, if you can manage and migrate the db then there is no reason why it's bad.

Comment: @Mjh & MarkBaker: I get your point, and you are correct. The main problem is that there is no proper upgrade system/script yet. I'm the sole programmer responsible for the development of the entire system (except the UI). Because of time constraints the company is already implementing the system for some of our customers. While the parts that are finished work fine, I do regularly go back and make changes or add extra functionalities or objects. And because I haven't had time to make an upgrade system yet (other functionalities have *higher priority*), I have to manually upgrade all customers.

Comment: I feel your "pain" and I'm sorry I have nothing substantial to contribute to make your job or this process easier. However, it appears you do understand everything and yes, it's not easy to be a sole developer. If your string-based approach shortens the amount of work you have to do, then I'd say it's the correct approach for your specific use-case.